# Javascript function not getting called properly in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am basically building a form for my project.
Here is plunkr URL for the project:     https://plnkr.co/edit/FNx7t48XFOJHrFzIpd1R?p

1. MainController.js: This has a factory called `FormDataService` which tracks user's input into the form and saves the data to Angular's front-end model in real time.
2. 129.html: This is the view where question lives on.
3. Sample.json: I use this format of json files to feed the view for 129.html
4. 129Ctrl.js: Just a controller
5. app.js: I define the routes for views using ngroutes

In my `129Ctrl.js`, I'm adding $scope.formData = {};. This lets me to save what user inputs into `formData`. The problem is that when the user refreshes, the `formData` does not persist. FormDataService in MainController.js is supposed to do that work, but I'm not sure why it isn't doing it.

Comment: what does Angular's front-end model in real time means?

Comment: Your plunkr is not working at all.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: edited. please check whether it works

Answer (score 0):

when the user refreshes the page your `controller` is initialized again 
and all your declared variables and scopes are reset.

if you want to use Angular's front-end model in real time you can use `$localStorage` or `$sessionStorage` from [this repo](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

there are other repositories as well.

this way data will persist during the life time of your application,
 even when user refreshes the page.

Comment: I'm using localStorage. pLease refer to my plunkr code. It's in MainController.js